# Using simple-dtpicker javascript set limitions to "from" and "to" date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using simple-dtpicker javascript for 2 fields "from" and "to".
I want to validate date selection onchange of these fields like "from" < dates < "to".

```
$('#txt-to-date').change(function() {
    $('#txt-from-date').appendDtpicker({
        maxDate: $('#txt-to-date').val() // when the end time changes, update the maxDate on the start field
    });
});

$('#txt-from-date').change(function() {
    $('#txt-to-date').appendDtpicker({
        minDate: $('#txt-from-date').val() // when the start time changes, update the minDate on the end field
    });
});
$('#txt-to-date').trigger('change');
$('#txt-from-date').trigger('change');
```

I have tried this but its not working.
Help me for validation.

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/5vbLyhrj/)?

**CODE**

```
$('input').appendDtpicker({ "futureOnly": true,todayButton : false});

$('#start_time').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#end_time').handleDtpicker('destroy');
    $('#end_time').val($this.val());
    $('#end_time').appendDtpicker({
        todayButton : false,
        minDate: $this.val()
    });
});
$('#start_time').trigger('change');
```

Comment: your explanation helps me but i did not got correct validation as per my requirement

Answer (score 0):

As per my requirement validation is below

```
$('input').appendDtpicker({ "futureOnly": false,todayButton : true});
             $('#txt-to-date').change(function() {
                $('#txt-from-date').handleDtpicker('destroy');
                $('#txt-from-date').appendDtpicker({
                    maxDate: $('#txt-to-date').val()
                });
             });

            $('#txt-from-date').change(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $('#txt-to-date').handleDtpicker('destroy');
                    $('#txt-to-date').val($this.val());
                    $('#txt-to-date').appendDtpicker({
                        todayButton : false,
                        minDate: $this.val(),
                        maxDate: curdate
                    });
            });
            $('#txt-from-date').trigger('change');
```